# Logarithmic norm wrt. the spectral norm

Tags: matrices, limits, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The [logarithmic norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_norm) (which is in fact not a norm) for a matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is defined by

$$
\mu[A] = \lim_{h\to +0} \frac{\|I+hA\|-1}{h}.
$$

For the spectral norm it is “known” that it holds

$$
\mu_2[A] = \lim_{h\to +0} \frac{\|I+hA\|_2-1}{h} = \lambda_\mathrm{max}\bigl(\tfrac12(A+A^T)\bigr).
$$

Unfortunately I can't (at the moment) find a source where this is proved, nor am I able to rigorously prove it, although it makes sense to me.

Comment: The linked wikipedia article defines $$ \mu [A] := \lim_{h \searrow 0} \frac{\|I \mathbin{\color{red}+} hA\| - 1}{h} $$

Comment: Fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in \mathbf R^n$ with $|x| = 1$. We have
\begin{align*}\def\a#1{\left|#1\right|}
  \a{\def\1{\mathop{\rm id}}\1x + hAx}^2 &= \def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}\<x+hAx, x+ hAx>\\
   &= \a x^2 + h\<Ax,x> + h\<A^tx,x> + h^2\<Ax,Ax>\\
   &= 1 + h\<(A+A^t)x,x> + h^2\a{Ax}^2
\end{align*}
Hence for $h > 0$:
$$ \def\n#1{\left\|#1\right\|}
  \n{\1 + hA}^2 = 1 + h\sup_{\a x = 1}\bigl(\<(A^t + A)x,x> + h\a{Ax}^2\bigr)
$$
As $\n{\1 + hA} + 1 \to 2$, $h \to 0$, we have 
\begin{align*}
  \mu[A] &= \lim_{h \searrow 0} \frac{\n{1+hA} - 1}{h}\\
         &= \lim_{h\searrow 0} \frac 1{\n{1+hA} + 1} \frac{\n{1+hA}^2 - 1}{h}\\
         &= \frac 12 \lim_{h\searrow 0} \sup_{\a x = 1}\bigl(\<(A^t + A)x,x> + h\a{Ax}^2\bigr)\\
         &= \frac 12 \sup_{\a x = 1}\<(A^t + A)x,x>\\
         &= \frac 12 \lambda_{\max}(A^t  +A)
\end{align*}

Comment: Except for the last line, where you use $\sup_{|x|=1}\langle Bx,x\rangle = \lambda_\mathrm{max} (B)$, this works for any (real) scalar product and its induced vector and matrix norms, right?

Comment: Right${}{}{}{}{}$.